# Looking for clarification of concepts when Ax = y for sparse solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

I am hoping for some clarification where I've indicated my understanding in blockquotes:

Starting from the definition of an $\ s$-sparse vector as:
A vector $\ x \in \mathbb{R}^{N} $ is called $\ s$-sparse if at most $\ s $ of its entries are nonzero, i.e. if

$\ \|x\|_{\ell_0} := card(supp(x))\le s $ where $\ supp(x) := \{j \in [N] : x_j \ne 0\} $ and $\ [N] = \{1, 2, ..., N\} $

and given a matrix $\ A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times N} $, $\ m<N $, these properties are said to be [equivalent](http://www.cis.pku.edu.cn/faculty/vision/zlin/A%20Mathematical%20Introduction%20to%20Compressive%20Sensing.pdf) (page 49 - Theorem 2.13):

1) every $\ s$-sparse vector $\ x \in \mathbb{R}^{N} $  is the unique $\ s$-sparse solution  of $\ Az = Ax $, that is, if $\ Ax = Az $ and both $\ x $ and $\ z $ are $\ s$-sparse , then $\ x = z $.

> So $\ Ax - Az = A(x-z) = A(0) = 0 $

2) the nullspace $\ N(A)$ does not contain any $\ 2s$-sparse vector other than the zero vector, that is, $\ N(A) \cap\{z \in \mathbb{R}^N : \|z\|_{\ell_0} \le 2s\} = \{0\}  $.

> No $\ 2s$-sparse vector $\ z$ exists within the nullspace. How do I show/see this for myself?

3) For every $\ S \subset [N]$ with $\ card(S) \le 2s$, the submatrix $\ A_s $ is injective as a map from  $\mathbb{R}^{S} $ to $\mathbb{R}^{m} $.

> This means that for $\ Az = y $ there is no other matrix $\ A_s \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times S}$ made from chosing a different subset of $\ S$ (i.e. at most $\ 2s$) column vectors of $\ A$ that will map an $\ s$-sparse vector $\ z$ to the same solution $\ y$.

4) Every set of $\ 2s $ columns of $\ A $ is linearly independent.

> What should I try to see this for myself? Currently seems to me that there is a chance I would select 2 linearly dependent vectors within some random choice of a set of $\ 2s$ column vectors.

How does the choice of 2s come up? (why not 3s or some other number?)

Comment: What is the definition of an $S$-sparse vector?

Comment: @user89987 added definition of S-sparse vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been answering your questions on the DSP stack exchange, but I'll take a shot here as well.

Let's start at the end:  **Why $2s$?**  I think the key point you are missing is that the $\ell_0$ "norm" is subadditive:  $||x + z||_0 \leq ||x||_0 + ||y||_0$, with equality iff the supports are disjoint.  So, if $x$ and $z$ are both $s$-sparse, then $x-z$ is no more than $2s$ sparse.

Let's show (2) implies (1).  Let $x$ and $z$ be $s$-sparse vectors, with $y = Ax = Az$.  Then $A(x-z) = 0$.  But $||x - z||_0 \leq 2s$, and by (2) the only $2s$ sparse vector in $N(A)$ is $0$.  So we must have $x=z$.

The rest of the implications follow using very similar arguments.